# Extract elements with specific names from JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to JavaScript, so please excuse my ignorance of basics and proper vocabulary.

**I have a list of objects all containing specific information/variables/elements (latitde and longitude) which I would like to have in separate arrays.**

```
 var data = [{
     "0": "44",
     "latitude": "44",
     "1": "11",
     "longitude": "11"
 }, {
     "0": "45",
     "latitude": "45",
     "1": "12",
     "longitude": "12"
 }, {
     "0": "46",
     "latitude": "46",
     "1": "13",
     "longitude": "13"
 }, {
     "0": "47",
     "latitude": "47",
     "1": "14",
     "longitude": "14"
 }];
```

I know already that I can access specific values easily:

```
data[1].latitude
data[1].longitude
```

But how do I put them together to get something like this? :

```
var latitude = [44, 45, 46, 47]
var longitude = [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to @Darin Dimitrov, but using  [**.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of array

> `Array.prototype.map()` Creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on
>   every element in this array.

**Updates:** It should have been like this

```
var lat = data.map( function(item) {
   return item.latitude;
});

var lon = data.map( function(item) {
   return item.longitude;
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8uMc/1/)

Comment: So why use `.map`. What about using `.forEach` instead? `.map` will generate a new array with values returned from the callback.

Comment: @NULL actually my code should have been like `var lat = data.map( function(item) {
   return item.latitude;
});

var lon = data.map( function(item) {
   return item.longitude;
});

alert(lat);
alert(lon);` So know I can say that *forEach runs a function on each array member and doesn't return anything.*

Comment: @marvin_dpr I don't understand `it did not work putting it in an HTML`  Is something like in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K8uMc/3/

Comment: sorry, there was something odd going on in the file - this solution works like a charm.

Comment: @marvin_dpr oh, Glad to help you my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through the elements of the `data` array and add the desired values to other arrays that will hold the result:

```
var latitudes = [];
var longitudes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    latitudes.push(data[i].latitude);
    longitudes.push(data[i].longitude);
}

// at this stage the latitudes and longitudes arrays 
// will contain the desired values
```

Also in your `data` array, the latitudes and longitudes are strings whereas in your expected arrays you want integers. So you might need to parse the values using the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function before adding them to the resulting arrays.

```
latitudes.push(parseInt(data[i].latitude, 10));
longitudes.push(parseInt(data[i].longitude, 10));
```

or with the [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function if those strings could represent decimal numbers (which is more realistic for latitudes and longitudes).

Comment: Thx, is there a way to do it without a loop?

Comment: No, of course not. Well, if you know in advance how many elements the array will contain you could repeat this code as many times as elements you have by replacing the `i` variable with a hardcoded integer :-) (No, I am kidding, don't do that)